# is it possible make changes changes on source file on yocto recipes and take effect?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

pls let me know if this question is invalid.
I have include http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-crypto/botan/botan_2.14.0.bb?h=master in my yocto build.
I just curious is it possible for me to add line of code in one of the library source file? for example i like to add stdout
in function
`void CBC_Decryption::finish(secure_vector<uint8_t>& buffer, size_t offset)` located in
/home/kjlau/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/botan/2.14.0-r0/package/usr/src/debug/botan/2.14.0-r0/Botan-2.14.0/src/lib/modes/cbc/cbc.cpp

something as shown below

```
void CBC_Decryption::finish(secure_vector<uint8_t>& buffer, size_t offset)
   {
     std::cout<<" CBC_Decryption::finish"<<std::endl;

   BOTAN_STATE_CHECK(state().empty() == false);
   BOTAN_ASSERT(buffer.size() >= offset, "Offset is sane");
   const size_t sz = buffer.size() - offset;

   const size_t BS = block_size();

   if(sz == 0 || sz % BS)
      throw Decoding_Error(name() + ": Ciphertext not a multiple of block size");

   update(buffer, offset);

   const size_t pad_bytes = BS - padding().unpad(&buffer[buffer.size()-BS], BS);
   buffer.resize(buffer.size() - pad_bytes); // remove padding
   if(pad_bytes == 0 && padding().name() != "NoPadding")
      {
      throw Decoding_Error("Invalid CBC padding");
      }
   }
```

If i can make this changes, how to compile it to ensure it take effect? i tried bitbake botan  or bitbake on application side, i do not observe changes take place.
Let me know if this is this a invalid question, thanks

Comment: create a `.patch` file by diffing two complete source trees and add it to `SRC_URI`  through .bbappend for recipe

Comment: @PraveenMuthusamy, your suggestion should be an answer ;)
@kj-lau you can also use `devtool` with `devtool modify botan` then modify the sources in the devtool workspace, create a commit for it and then `git format-patch HEAD^`to create the patch. Then create a bbappend with the patch in `SRC_URI`. Apparently the `git format-patch` and bbappend things can be done with `devtool update-recipe botan -a <some_layer>` but i've never done it before. See https://embeddedguruji.blogspot.com/2019/02/using-devtool-in-yocto-to.html